# substringWithRange out of bounds--what am I missing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrange, nsrangeexception

I'm trying to extract some strings from some code, and I'm coming up against an `NSRangeException` I don't understand.  Here's my code:

```
NSString *start = @"<strong><span class='target'>";
NSString *end = @"</span></strong> ";

NSRange startRange = [stringToScan rangeOfString:start];
NSRange endRange = [stringToScan rangeOfString:end];
NSRange targetRange;
targetRange.length = endRange.location - startRange.location - startRange.length;
targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
NSString *adlerNumber = [stringToScan substringWithRange:targetRange];
NSLog(@"%@",adlerNumber);

NSString *startHeadword = @"Translated headword: </strong>";
NSString *endHeadword = @"<strong class=";

NSRange startRangeHeadword = [stringToScan rangeOfString:startHeadword]; //logs as e.g. location 773, length 29
NSRange endRangeHeadword = [stringToScan rangeOfString:endHeadword]; //logs as e.g. location 809
NSRange targetRangeHeadword;
targetRangeHeadword.length = endRangeHeadword.location - startRangeHeadword.location - startRangeHeadword.length; //logs as e.g. 27
targetRangeHeadword.location = startRangeHeadword.location + startRangeHeadword.length; // logs as e.g. 2496
NSString *translatedHeadword = [stringToScan substringWithRange:targetRangeHeadword];
```

`adlerNumber` is created and logs without error.  But then trying to create `translatedHeadword` (last line of code above) gives me this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {2634, 2147481013} out of bounds; string length 9309'
```

If `targetRangeHeadword.length` logs as 27 and `targetRangeHeadword.location` logs as 2496, how can I be getting the numbers the `NSRangeException` is giving me?  And how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help, guys and gals.

Comment: Also, make sure this: `class='target'` is not actually reading this: `class="target"`. For `NSString`, `(' != ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some `NSLog`s to see more numbers, such as `stringToScan.length`.

"*If `targetRangeHeadword.length` logs as 27 and `targetRangeHeadword.location` logs as 2496, how can I be getting the numbers the `NSRangeException`*"

Try to replace `targetRangeHeadword.location` with a magic number such as 2400 and `NSLog` it. Could it be that 2496 is the end of `stringToScan` ?

**-EDIT:** I just noticed:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {2634, 2147481013} out of bounds; string length 9309'
```

**Specifically** `Range {2634, 2147481013}`, means one of your closing tags `</>` are not found.

This number "2147481013" is an indicator that something was not found.

Comment: Thanks so much--I went through and tediously logged EVERYTHING and that showed me where the error was!

Answer (score 0):

`startRangeHeadword` was not found, it's `location` was `NSNotFound` or possibly another search returned `NSNotFound`. You must check that NSRange location is not `NSNotFound` after any search (`rangeOfString`). Error checking is a pain but really must be done.

Single step through your code and watch the range `location` for `NSNotFound` (a large number).

As an alternative consider `NSScanner`, it is probably better suited to your needs.

Comment: Thanks--but before I posted this I did single step through the code, and all the ranges logged locations--I think I commented the code above with what the locations were.  :(  But I'll go check out NSScanner.

Comment: When you get a location or range like 2147481013 there is a problem and it is usually due to NSNotFound that on 32 bit system is 2147483647. In any event a length of 2147481013 it most likely an error, find where that come from.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using NSRegularExpressions here coupled with the rangeOfString method. That way you can grab all of the instances of a particular pattern and replace them with whatever you want or extract them. A good site to practice these is here: www.regexr.com